# Need html Validator with little to no dependencies

Tags: html, validation

I am attempting to install an HTML validator on a secure server with no Internet access. I tried to install the W3 validator, but that had many perl dependencies that in turn had more perl dependencies that it was proving rather difficult to download them all then transfer them to the server and install them manually.

I need a validator with little to no extra dependencies that I can download to my personal computer then transfer the files, install and quickly setup on a server with no Internet access.

Our validation server is within a LAN that has no Internet access.

Comment: Not saying its not worth the trouble but why would you want to do this ? It is afterall HTML pages you are wanting to validate which in the end will be displayed via the web? Is this because you are developing on a server which is within a LAN and has no outside access and you want to be able to validate code on it or for another purpose?

Comment: Do you need a full solution with a front end (like the w3c vaildator) or just a library you can call?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about its dependencies, but have you looked at validator.nu?

Comment: That's nonsense. validator.nu was written from scratch, and was later integrated into the W3C validator (when the W3C realised HTML5 existed and adopted it).

Comment: You're right, validator.nu is not dependent on having W3C. However, it's install script does download a lot.